# Can a Rasa project have both RegexEntityExtractor and RegexFeaturizer in the pipeline if using lookup tables?

Tags: components, lookup-tables, rasa

Aren't both rasa components conflicting? If using one or another, what are the configurations I should look at?

I've been trying unsuccessfully to use lookup tables with both components. Any workable solution out there?

Answer (score 0):

As per Rasa's documentation, I guess you cannot use RegexFeaturizer and RegexEntityExtractor together as they both do the same job. Please try the following way.
inside config.yml add the following changes:

```yaml
    pipeline:
    - name: RegexEntityExtractor
      # text will be processed with case insensitive as default
      case_sensitive: False
      # use lookup tables to extract entities
      use_lookup_tables: True
      # use regexes to extract entities
      use_regexes: True
      # use match word boundaries for lookup table
      use_word_boundaries: True
```

Note: Above example is a section of the whole pipeline where there can be other components.

Make sure to add lookup tables inside nlu file/folder, mention one example from a lookup table inside training data, as shown below:

```yaml
nlu:
- lookup: country
  examples: |
    - France
    - Germany
    - India
    - USA
 - intent: address
   examples: |
   - I stay in [USA](country)
   - I live in [USA](country)
```

This will help RegexEntityExtractor to understand the extraction and will be able to extract. I am unsure if it would be good to use RegexFeaturizer and EntityExtractor together. I have tried this and it works perfectly fine.

For more information on RegexEntityExtractor please refer [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components#regexentityextractor)
and for using it with training examples please checkout [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu-training-data#lookup-tables)

Feel free to ask questions regarding this if you face any difficulties.

Comment: Thanks Dishant for clarifying the question so elegantly and clear. It really worked!